# Número de reproducciones de un video youtube

Tags: html

Si pegamos en un bloc de notas el siguiente código html con estensión .txt ,

```
<iframe width="780" height="428" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/s0Pjpj4fbgU?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&hd=1&rel=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

después lo guardamos con extensión .html y lo ejecutamos con doble clic izquierdo, podremos verlo incrustado en una página web, pero aunque es un vídeo almacenado en youtube, no se muestra con el reproductor de youtube y por ello no se contabiliza en el número de reproducciones del mismo.

Comment: y cuál es el problema ? o acaso estás intentando hacer un tutorial de bajos recursos?

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a que el número de visitas no aumenta, es porque youtube [valida las visualizaciones](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=es).

Si lo que deseas en agregar el número de visualizaciones en tu sitio web, puedes obtener el número de reproducciones con el API de Youtube v3:

Para esto tienes que usar el servicio rest de youtube para obtener los datos de un video, según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) de youtube v3 puedes obtener un campo llamado `viewCount`, mira el siguiente ejemplo con jQuery:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Q5mHPo2yDG8&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

```js
var video = 'k2B5Kg-AIyo';
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyDDBk8tAkod1VRRNyFZF09fgQyMpnSe5HI'; //para obtener tu key tienes que ir a https://console.developers.google.com

$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + video + '&key=' + apiKey, function(data) {
  $('#visitas').text(data.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
  $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t')); // imprime la respuesta del servicio
});
$("#yt").attr("src", 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="yt"></iframe>
<h1>Visitas: <span id="visitas"></span></h1>

<pre></pre>
```